# Intensive job javascript, browser freez

Tags: javascript, arrays, multithreading

I got a blob to construct, and received almost 100 parts of (500k) to decrypt and construct a blob file.

Actually it's working fine, but when i do my decryption, that take processor, and freeze my page.

I try different approach, with defered of jquery, timeout but always the same probleme.

It's there a ways to not freez the UI thread ?

```
var parts = blobs.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.part - b.part;
    })
    // notre bytesarrays finales


  var byteArrays = [];
  i = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++) 
{
// That job is intensive, and take time
        byteArrays.push(that.decryptBlob(parts[i].blob.b64, fileType));
      }

  // create new blob with all data
  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: fileType });
```

Comment: Use [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks to Sebastian Simon,

I took the avenue of worker. And it's working fine.

```
    var chunks = [];
       var decryptedChucnkFnc = function (args) {
           // My builder blob job here
      }
      // determine the number of maximum worker to use
      var maxWorker = 5;
      if (totalParts < maxWorker) {
        maxWorker = totalParts;
      }
      for (var iw = 0; iw < maxWorker; iw++) {

        eval('var w' + iw + ' = new Worker("decryptfile.min.js")');
        var wo = eval("w" + iw);
        var item = blobs.pop();
        wo.postMessage(MyObjectPassToTheFile);
        wo.onmessage = decryptedChucnkFnc;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The body inside for(...) loop is synchronous, so the entire decryption process is synchronous, in simple words, decryption happens chunk after chunk. How about making it asynchronous ? Like decrypting multiple chunks in parallel. In JavaScript terminology we can use **Asynchronous Workers**. These workers can work in parallel, so if you spawn 5 workers for example. The total time is reduced by T / 5. (T = total time in synchronous mode).

Read more about worker threads here : 
https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-multithreading-what-are-worker-threads-and-why-do-they-matter-48ab102f8b10/